# How to put all the answers to an equation in one "alert" using "for"?

Tags: html, loops, for-loop

I am making a program in which I ask for a range of 2 numbers and it resolves all the equations with the numbers of the range. The problem is that I know how to put them inside the "for", but I want all the answers outside of the "for" in one "alert"

I have tried to accumulate the answers doing var1=var1+ result + \n but I still need to put what is "x" related to the answer "y". And doing what I did only shows you the results of "y"

Comment: Please show the relevant "*[mcve]*" code to reproduce your problem, and explain clearly how your code is "failing" (and in what way).

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.